# Testing installation of a browser plugin

Tags: plugins, browser, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm using selenium webdriver to test our website. We also have a browser plugin/extension that we'd like to test in the same way. As far as I can tell there isn't any way to test the installation of a plugin using webdriver. Is there any way to do it with webdriver? If not how might I go about automating testing installation of the plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems firefox and chrome will both allow you to register extensions using webdriver capabilities.

Here is the documentation for

Firefox: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver#Running_with_firebug

Chrome: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver#Chrome_Extensions

No support unfortunately, but this is a very good start.